# To update LocalStorage values from a dynamically created HTML table

Tags: javascript, local-storage

The HTML table is dynamically created with the function createTableRow(empDetail), which is working but when the rows/cells values are updated/changed it reflects in the HTML table but **I want the same respective changed values to get changed in LocalStorage against the respective id**. Help is needed for **function tableUpdate()**
Note: There is only one key i.e. empDetails and the same key has multiple id's of respective rows (Employee) created

```js
"use strict";

let addNewEmployee = document.getElementById("addNewEmployee");
let modal = document.getElementById("favDialog");
let closeModal = document.getElementById("cancelModal");
let modalForm = document.getElementById("modal-form");
let submitModal = document.getElementById("submitModal");

let tableContainerHeader = document.querySelector(".table-container-header");
let tableContainerContent = document.querySelector(".table-container-content");

let empTable = document.getElementById("employeeTable");

const showModal = addNewEmployee.addEventListener("click", function() {
  modal.showModal();
});

closeModal.addEventListener("click", function() {
  modal.close();
});

let employeeId = document.getElementById("employeeId");
let employeeName = document.getElementById("employeeName");
let designation = document.getElementById("designation");
let salary = document.getElementById("salary");
let uniqueEmpId = document.getElementById("empDetailId");

let tr = null;
let empDetails = [];

if (localStorage.getItem("empDetails")) {
  empDetails.map((empDetail) => {
    createTableRow(empDetail);
  });
}

let onModalSubmit = modal.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (tr == null) {

    if (employeeId && employeeName && designation && salary != "") {
      let empDetail = {
        id: new Date().getTime(),
        name: {
          employeeIdLocal: employeeId.value,
          employeeNameLocal: employeeName.value,
          designationLocal: designation.value,
          salaryLocal: salary.value,
          uniqueEmpId: new Date().getTime(),
        },
      };

      modal.close();

      empDetails.push(empDetail);

      localStorage.setItem("empDetails", JSON.stringify(empDetails));

      modalForm.reset();

      createTableRow(empDetail);
    }
  } else {
    tableUpdate(e);
  }
});

/////// Create Table Row

function createTableRow(empDetail) {

  const tEmployeeMarkup = `
  <tr class="fullEmpDetail">
    <td id="teId">${empDetail.name.employeeIdLocal}</td>
    <td id="teName">${empDetail.name.employeeNameLocal}</td>
    <td id="teDesignation">${empDetail.name.designationLocal}</td>
    <td id="teSalary">$${empDetail.name.salaryLocal}</td>
    <td>
      <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
      <i value="Edit" type="button" id="update-row" class="edit-row fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
      <i value="Delete" type="button" class="remove-row fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </td>
    <td id="empDetailId" class="empDetailId">${empDetail.id}</td>
  </tr>
`;

  empTable.innerHTML += tEmployeeMarkup;

  document.getElementById("modal-form").reset();
}


///////  Remove Row

function onDeleteRow(e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains("remove-row")) {

    return;
  }

  const btn = e.target;
  btn.closest("tr").remove();
}

tableContainerContent.addEventListener("click", onDeleteRow);

//////////// Edit Row

tableContainerContent.addEventListener("click", onEditRow);

function onEditRow(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("edit-row")) {


    modal.showModal();


    tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    // console.log(tr);

    let tableEmpId = tr.cells[0].textContent;
    let tableEmpName = tr.cells[1].textContent;
    let tableEmpDesignation = tr.cells[2].textContent;
    let tableEmpSalary = tr.cells[3].textContent;

    employeeId.value = tableEmpId;
    employeeName.value = tableEmpName;
    designation.value = tableEmpDesignation;
    salary.value = tableEmpSalary;
  }
}

///////////////// Update Row

function tableUpdate(e) {
  let tableEmpId = document.getElementById("teId");
  let tableEmpName = document.getElementById("teName");
  let tableEmpDesignation = document.getElementById("teDesignation");
  let tableEmpSalary = document.getElementById("teSalary");

  tr.cells[0].textContent = employeeId.value;
  tr.cells[1].textContent = employeeName.value;
  tr.cells[2].textContent = designation.value;
  tr.cells[3].textContent = salary.value;


  modalForm.reset();
  modal.close();

  let tableEmpIDs = document.querySelectorAll(".empDetailId");

  let empDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("empDetails"));

  for (let row = 0; row < tableEmpIDs.length; row++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < empDetails.length; i++) {
      empDetails[i].name.employeeIdLocal = tableEmpId.textContent;
      empDetails[i].name.employeeNameLocal = tableEmpName.textContent;
      empDetails[i].name.designationLocal = tableEmpDesignation.textContent;
      empDetails[i].name.salaryLocal = tableEmpSalary.textContent;
      break;
    }
  }

  localStorage.setItem("empDetails", JSON.stringify(empDetails));


}
```

```css
table
/* th,
td,
tr  */

{
  border: black solid 1px;
  width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
}

table td,
table th {
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 200px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.fas {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.empDetailIdHeader,
.empDetailId {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <h2>Employee Details</h2>
    <button id="addNewEmployee">+ Add New Employee</button>
    <div class="table-container-header">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Employee ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Designation</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
          <th>Action</th>
          <th class="empDetailIdHeader">Local Storage ID</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="table-container-content">
      <table id="employeeTable">

      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Model Code -->
  <div id="#modal-container">
    <dialog id="favDialog">
      <h2>Enter Employee Details</h2>
      <form id="modal-form" method="dialog">
        <section>
          <p>
            <label for="employeeId">Employee ID: </label
              ><input type="text" id="employeeId" />
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="employeeName">Name: </label
              ><input type="text" id="employeeName" />
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="designation">Designation: </label
              ><input type="text" id="designation" />
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="salary">Salary: </label
              ><input type="text" id="salary" />
            </p>
          </section>
          <menu>
            <button id="cancelModal" type="reset">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" id="submitModal">SUBMIT</button>
          </menu>
        </form>
      </dialog>
    </div>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: may try just to edit the empDetails array and e.g. on edit just get the employe object with `let employee =  empDetails` and set the properties accordingly and write a small function that renders the table by clearing it just (just delete the inner html of the table), calls the your  createTableRow function for each element in the employe array and you call it everytime somthing changes. That would it make easier to you. Also saving and loading would be just to set or read the array from  local storage :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be better off just writing the JSON from scratch each time, rather than trying to update it. Something like...

```
let entries = document.querySelectorAll("table.empDetailsTable tr");
let json = [], props = ['employeeIdLocal', 'employeeNameLocal', 'designationLocal', 'salaryLocal'] // in order that they appear in the table
entries.forEach(row => {
  let data = {}
  row.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((el, i) => {
    data[props[i]] = el.innerText;
  })
  json.push(data);
})

localStorage.setItem("empDetails", JSON.stringify(data));
```

I didn't understand your data structure, but hopefully this will suffice or point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thankss @kinglish and mucksh for your replies.  Writing JSON from scratch also works too, but I tried updating the localStorage using the same key and same respective ID's (of each employee that was created) . The ways which I implemented it : declared let tr = null in global scope and tr kept on changing as per the employee row selected, declared let editID = "" in global scope and picked the id from respective tr. Used data attribute to create id for each tr/employee. Posting the entire JS code in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

To update LocalStorage values from a dynamically created HTML table

```
let addNewEmployee = document.getElementById("addNewEmployee");
let modal = document.getElementById("favDialog");
let closeModal = document.getElementById("cancelModal");
let modalForm = document.getElementById("modal-form");
let submitModal = document.getElementById("submitModal");

let tableContainerHeader = document.querySelector(".table-container-header");
let tableContainerContent = document.querySelector(".table-container-content");

let empTable = document.getElementById("employeeTable");

const showModal = addNewEmployee.addEventListener("click", function () {
  modal.showModal();
});

closeModal.addEventListener("click", function () {
  modal.close();
});

let employeeId = document.getElementById("employeeId");
let employeeName = document.getElementById("employeeName");
let designation = document.getElementById("designation");
let salary = document.getElementById("salary");
let uniqueEmpId = document.getElementById("empDetailId");

let tr = null;
let empDetails = [];

//edit

let editID = "";

let onModalSubmit = modal.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (tr == null && addNewEmployee) {
    if (employeeId && employeeName && designation && salary != "") {
      let empDetail = {
        id: new Date().getTime(),
        name: {
          employeeIdLocal: employeeId.value,
          employeeNameLocal: employeeName.value,
          designationLocal: designation.value,
          salaryLocal: salary.value,
          uniqueEmpId: new Date().getTime(),
        },
      };

      modal.close();

      empDetails.push(empDetail);

      localStorage.setItem("empDetails", JSON.stringify(empDetails));

      modalForm.reset();

      createTableRow(empDetail);
    }
  } else {
    tableUpdate(tr);

    tr = null;
  }
});

/////// Create Table Row

function createTableRow(empDetail) {
  const element = document.createElement("tr");
  let attr = document.createAttribute("data-id");
  attr.value = empDetail.id;
  element.setAttributeNode(attr);
  element.classList.add("fullEmpDetail");
  element.innerHTML = `
    <td id="teId">${empDetail.name.employeeIdLocal}</td>
    <td id="teName">${empDetail.name.employeeNameLocal}</td>
    <td id="teDesignation">${empDetail.name.designationLocal}</td>
    <td id="teSalary">$${empDetail.name.salaryLocal}</td>
    <td>
      <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
      <i value="Edit" type="button" id="update-row" class="edit-row fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
      <i value="Delete" type="button" class="remove-row fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </td>
`;

  empTable.appendChild(element);

  document.getElementById("modal-form").reset();
}

///////  Remove Row

function onDeleteRow(e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains("remove-row")) {
    return;
  }

  const btn = e.target;
  btn.closest("tr").remove();
}

tableContainerContent.addEventListener("click", onDeleteRow);

//////////// Edit Row

tableContainerContent.addEventListener("click", onEditRow);

function onEditRow(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("edit-row")) {
    modal.showModal();

    tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    // console.log(tr);

    let tableEmpId = tr.cells[0].textContent;
    let tableEmpName = tr.cells[1].textContent;
    let tableEmpDesignation = tr.cells[2].textContent;
    let tableEmpSalary = tr.cells[3].textContent;

    employeeId.value = tableEmpId;
    employeeName.value = tableEmpName;
    designation.value = tableEmpDesignation;
    salary.value = tableEmpSalary;
  }
}

///////////////// Update Row

function tableUpdate(tr) {
  let tableEmpId = document.getElementById("teId");
  let tableEmpName = document.getElementById("teName");
  let tableEmpDesignation = document.getElementById("teDesignation");
  let tableEmpSalary = document.getElementById("teSalary");

  console.log(tr);

  tr.cells[0].textContent = employeeId.value;
  tr.cells[1].textContent = employeeName.value;
  tr.cells[2].textContent = designation.value;
  tr.cells[3].textContent = salary.value;

  editID = tr.dataset.id;

  modalForm.reset();
  modal.close();

  editLocalStorage(editID, tr);
}

///////// Edit Local Storage

function editLocalStorage(editID, tr) {
  let empDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("empDetails"));

  empDetails = empDetails.map((empDetail) => {
    if (empDetail.id === parseInt(editID)) {
      empDetail.name.employeeIdLocal = tr.cells[0].textContent;
      empDetail.name.employeeNameLocal = tr.cells[1].textContent;
      empDetail.name.designationLocal = tr.cells[2].textContent;
      empDetail.name.salaryLocal = tr.cells[3].textContent;
    }
    return empDetail;
  });
  localStorage.setItem("empDetails", JSON.stringify(empDetails));
}
```